# Add Folders On Remote Servers With PowerShell

Tags: powershell, directory, new-item

there's got to be something blatantly obvious on this one that I'm doing wrong, but I need another set of eyes to help me out because I'm not getting any errors - it's just not doing what I want...  I need to push a software installer file to "X:\folder\Software Install Files" and backup the existing files to "X:\folder\Software Backups" on a bunch of different servers.  In order to do that, I need to make sure these folders exist first and create them if they don't.  The script below gathers the $computer variable from a servers.txt file, then for each computer I look to the registry to find out what drive the software is currently installed on, then create the appropriate folders on the drive if they don't exist:

```
# This file contains the list of Servers
$computers = gc "C:\Folder\Subfolder\Servers.txt"

clear-host

# The Command below pulls all the variables above and performs the file copy
foreach ($computer in $computers) {

#Gather Version and Program Directory Information from Registry


    $machinename = $computer
    $icakey = "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Program\\Program"
    $ICAVers = "Version"
    $ICADrive = "InstallDir"

    $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', 
$machinename)
    $icaregkey = $reg.opensubkey($icakey)
    $ICAV = $icaregkey.getvalue($IcaVers)
    $ICAD = $icaregkey.getvalue($IcaDrive)

#Declare Directory Drive Letter As Variable

    $DriveLetter,$Folder = $ICAD.split(":")

#Declare path for folders

    $Softwarepath = "\\$computer\$driveletter$\Folder\Software Install Files"
    $BackupPath = "\\$computer\$driveletter$\Folder\Software Backups"

#Create Software Folder

    If(test-Path -path $SoftwarePath)
        {Write-host "$SoftwarePath already exists on $computer" -ForegroundColor Red}
        ELSE
            {{New-Item -Path $SoftwarePath -ItemType Directory}
                {write-host "$SoftwarePath created on $computer"}}

#Create WebAccess Backups Folder

    If(test-Path -path $BackupPath)
        {Write-host "$BackupPath already exists on $computer" -ForegroundColor Red}
        ELSE
            {{New-Item -Path $BackupPath -ItemType Directory}
                {write-host "$BackupPath created on $computer"}}
```

The results I'm getting show this for every server in the servers.txt:

```
New-Item -Path $SoftwarePath -ItemType Directory
write-host "$SoftwarePath created on $computer"
New-Item -Path $BackupPath -ItemType Directory
write-host "$BackupPath created on $computer"
```

It's not actually creating the folder, and in previous times I've done something like this, the variables in the result displayed the value they were representing, and the "clear-host" at the top made sure the only result was the stuff that should have been in the write-host line.

Again, I feel like this is something blatantly obvious, but I'm tearing my hair out to figure it out.

Comment: Check the `$softwarepath` and `$Backuppath` variables. There is an extra $ character in there.

Comment: Are you referring to the $driveletter$?  That's to hit the X$ in the event the drive is not shared (it's typically not).  That last $ is not in orange like a variable would be.  I've actually used this format on a number of other scripts and it's worked fine... If that's not what you're referring to, I'm blind.

Comment: Yes that last $ should be escaped with a backtick I would think so powershell sees it as a normal character and not as a non-existing variable

Comment: That doesn't seem to be it.  Like I said, I use that format regularly.  Also, when I type $softwarepath and $backuppath into Powershell to see what's displayed, the result is 

    \\hostname\D$\Folder\Software Installs

and

    \\hostname\D$\Folder\Software Backups

So it seems to be seeing those properly.

Comment: Ok, then I'm just curious why you put so many `{...}` inside the `else` blocks

Comment: I'm pretty much an amateur at this stuff...  I wasn't sure where the Else would end and where the new steps would begin.  I surrounded the entire ELSE with a {}, then put each command in {} as well.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a long discussion in comments, I think I may have found what was missing in your code. Indeed it had to do with the paths you set up for `$Softwarepath` and `$BackupPath` where you forgot the `$` sign before `Folder`. The directories were probably created, but not where you expected them. They will have ended up in `\\computername\X$\Folder\Software Install Files`.

Anyway, here's a revised version of your code:

```
# This file contains the list of Servers
$computers = Get-Content "C:\Folder\Subfolder\Servers.txt"

clear-host

# The Command below pulls all the variables above and performs the file copy
foreach ($computer in $computers) {

    #Gather Version and Program Directory Information from Registry
    $machinename = $computer
    $icakey   = "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Program\\Program"
    $ICAVers  = "Version"
    $ICADrive = "InstallDir"

    $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $machinename)
    $icaregkey = $reg.opensubkey($icakey)
    $ICAV = $icaregkey.getvalue($IcaVers)
    $ICAD = $icaregkey.getvalue($IcaDrive)

    #Close the registry keys when done
    $icaregkey.Close()
    $reg.Close()

    #Declare Directory Drive Letter As Variable
    $DriveLetter,$Folder = $ICAD.split(":")

    #Declare path for folders
    $Softwarepath = "\\$computer\$driveletter$\$Folder\Software Install Files"
    $BackupPath   = "\\$computer\$driveletter$\$Folder\Software Backups"

    #Create Software Folder
    if(Test-Path -Path $SoftwarePath -PathType Container) { 
        Write-Host "$SoftwarePath already exists on $computer" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    else {
        New-Item -Path $SoftwarePath -ItemType Directory -Force
        Write-Host "$SoftwarePath created on $computer"
    }

    #Create WebAccess Backups Folder
    if(Test-Path -Path $BackupPath -PathType Container) {
        Write-Host "$BackupPath already exists on $computer" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
    else {
        New-Item -Path $BackupPath -ItemType Directory -Force
        Write-Host "$BackupPath created on $computer"
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: That's actually not it either.  The "Folder" in that line is not a variable and wasn't meant to be.  the $Folder variable was just used as a way to split the $ICAD variable and was never meant to be used again here (I needed the $driveletter variable).  There is only a handful of servers that I'm working with here, and can pretty easily go create this folder on each one - which it looks like I'm going to end up doing.  Just one of those things that's frustrating to not be able to figure out.

EDIT:  I figured it it out... I did have too many {} in my else statement.

Comment: Ah, the `$Folder` vs `Folder` was not clear to me. If all you wanted was the driveletter, maybe it would make the code a bit more readable if you would split like this: `$DriveLetter = $ICAD.split(":")[0]`. Anyway, glad it's fixed now.

Comment: HAHA!  Yeah, clear code :)  if I ever get the hang of this thing, I'll work on clearing up my code :)